# Why it's code not compile?

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity paralel_reg is
    generic ( default : positive := 4);
    port(C, notR, E: in std_logic; D: in std_logic_vector(default downto 1); 
    Q: out std_logic_vector(default downto 1)); 
end paralel_reg;

architecture paralel_reg of paralel_reg is
signal q : std_logic_vector(default downto 1);
begin
process (C, notR)
begin
    if notR = '0' then q <= (others => '0');
    else if rising_edge(C) then q <= D;  
    end if;
end process;  --# Error: COMP96_0019: paralel_register.vhd : (18, 5): Keyword "if" expected.
    --# Error: COMP96_0015: paralel_register.vhd : (18, 5): ';' expected.

process (E, q) --# Error: COMP96_0019: paralel_register.vhd : (24, 2): Keyword "end" expected.
begin
    if E = '0' then Q <= (others => '0');
    else Q <= q;        --# Error: COMP96_0019: paralel_register.vhd : (24, 2): Keyword "end" expected.
            --# Error: COMP96_0016: paralel_register.vhd : (24, 7): Design unit declaration expected.
    end if;
end process;
end paralel_reg;
```

> # Error: COMP96_0019: paralel_register.vhd : (18, 5): Keyword "if" expected.
>   # Error: COMP96_0015: paralel_register.vhd : (18, 5): ';' expected.
>   # Error: COMP96_0019: paralel_register.vhd : (21, 1): Keyword "end" expected.
>   # Error: COMP96_0019: paralel_register.vhd : (24, 2): Keyword "end" expected.
>   # Error: COMP96_0016: paralel_register.vhd : (24, 7): Design unit declaration expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
process (C, notR) begin
    if notR = '0' then q <= (others => '0');
    else if rising_edge(C) then q <= D;  
    end if; end process;
```

should be this:

```
process (C, notR)
begin
    if notR = '0' then q <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(C) then q <= D;  
    end if;
end process;
```

The VHDL `if` statement has this format:

```
if ... then
  ...
elsif ... then
  ...
elsif ... then
  ...
else
  ...
end if;
```

All VHDL statements end with a semicolon. The above is one statement, which ends with `end if;`. VHDL statements can be embedded with in another. So, you can embedded another `if` statement inside an `if` statement and this is what you are doing if you use `else if` rather than `elsif`:

```
if ... then
  ...
elsif ... then
  ...
elsif ... then
  ...
else
  IF ... THEN
    ...
  ELSIF ... THEN
    ...
  ELSE 
    ...
  END IF;
end if;
```

Every `if` statement in VHDL requires an `end if;`. Notice that in the above, with one `if` statement embedded within another, there are two `end if`s. So, you could have written:

```
process (C, notR) begin
    if notR = '0' then q <= (others => '0');
    else if rising_edge(C) then q <= D;  
    end if;
    end if; end process;
```

but I would always recommend `elsif` instead of `else if` because you need less `end if`s.

Answer (score 1):

"Else If" doesn't exist in VHDL, you must write:

```
IF ... THEN
ELSIF ... THEN
ELSE 
END IF;
```

Comment: You can use `else if` but then you have to pay closer attention to control flow and having matching `end if` statements. `q` and `Q` are lexically identical in VHDL and there are two declarations. Changing occurrences of `q` to `qi` (incl. the sensitivity list) and adding a second end if (or using elsif) and the code analyzes (compiles). The message here is that an answer should be proven.  Not sure what `E` is intended to do.